# Python not responding correctly to user input

Tags: python, spyder

I have been making a code to try to respond to the user input as a joke to send to a friend. But everytime I input a passcode it prints 'Access Denied.' And I'm using Spyder to code it.

Here is the code:

```
import time
print "Please enter your name to acess file."
userName=raw_input();
print "Searching Database..."
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Searching Database.."
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Searching Database."
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Searching Database.."
time.sleep(0.5)
print "Hello {} please input passcode.".format(userName)
passCode=raw_input();
if passCode != 0000:
    print 'Access Denied'
else:
    print 'Access Granted'
```

Comment: Try looking at `passCode` to see what it actually contains. You might also want to try looking at its `type()` (i.e. by running `type(passCode)` and comparing it to `type(0000)`.

Comment: `if passCode != 0000:`? or `if passCode != 0:` or `if passCode != '0000':`

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison is wrong. You are comparing the string pass with the `0000` which is a number.

```
if passCode != '0000':
    print 'Access Denied'
else:
    print 'Access Granted'
```

> 0x5453
>
> raw_input returns an object of type str, which should not be compared
>   to an object of type int.

Comment: To elaborate, `raw_input` returns an object of type `str`, which should not be compared to an object of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(passCode) != 0000:  # notice the integer wrapper
    print 'Access Denied'
else:
    print 'Access Granted'
```

Make sure you are comparing the right types. 
You can also do this:

```
if passCode != '0000':
    print 'Access Denied'
else:
    print 'Access Granted'
```